# How to get dependancy relationship between words using minipar parser in GATE

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, text-mining, gate

I am using GATE Developer 8.1 - an integrated development environment for language processing, on Windows.
I have run GATE against my document and got the different annotations. But I want dependency relationships between the words of a sentence which can be achieved using minipar parser available GATE and as show in https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch18.html#x23-42900018.1

After getting the annotations when I run the minipar parser on my document It is showing error:

> minipar.lsp can not be opened

Tried configuring minipar as described on
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ai.gate.general/3382

I've tried and also googled lot about it but not getting the solution.

I need to get the dependency relationships between the words of a sentence.
Please specify the process.

Please help.. Thanks in advance